# IOS: Problems about adding subviews (UIView) into UIScrollView instance

Tags: ios, scrollview

I used the following code to init a instance of Home Class (Home.m Home.h Home.xib), that Home.m is the viewcontroller of Home.xib, I added a UIButton in the view of Home.xib, and then init the Home instance in the another viewcontroller, and added it into UIScrollView instance.

The problem is that when I click the button in the subview that was created from Home, the app crashed. any helps?!

```
CGFloat yOrigin = i* self.view.frame.size.width;
Home *newView = [[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];
newView.view.frame = CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[scroll addSubview:[newView view]];
[newView release];
```

Comment: Please, post your crash log and what exactly is your Home class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the view of a view controller as a subview to another view, you need to retain the view controller. The view controller here will be released while its view is retained, which might be the source of the crash

(crash logs would help)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [PageControl sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple. I hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do ?

In you posted code,

- 1- you alloc your ViewController (Home)
- 2- you add the Home's subview to another view
- 3- you release your Home.

So retain count of Home is = 0, so at end of execution loop, Home is deleted and its view too.

Put your Home ViewController in your .h file, alloc it at class creation and release it at dealloc.